3D Layered/Stacked images? How?
I came across this image whilst i was randomly browsing and I wondered how it's created. I think this technique would be useful in presenting information on a powerpoint and the like but I'm not sure how to go about doing creating one for myself. For reference I have fairly basic graphic design skills in Figma and not really a photoshop expert. Would appreciate any help i can get, anything from websites/app that can help transform flat images into layered layout (i don't know what this technique is called!) to tutorials somewhere on web or any other direction you can provide, i'll take anything :) Thanks
Edition by Rafael. I am posting a screen capture of the home page so the credits are shown; capacitorjs.com


Does this answer your question? How to achieve this 3D "Card" effect

@Scott thanks, that was useful. Als i found the term is called "Isometric" so was able to find something in Figma called SkewDat (https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/741472919529947576/skewdat) that seems to be fairly easy to use for what i need to get close to the original image i shared.

That can even be done with CSS only n_n and also with full 3D software.
